# The set of numbers of the following form that are cubes

Tags: roots, integers

I have found this problem in a 10th grade textbook and it's given me headaches trying to solve it. It says, determine the set:

$$ A = \left \{ x \in \mathbb Z| \root3\of{\frac{7x+2}{x+5}} \in \mathbb Z\right \} $$

So I have to find a condition for x so that the expression under the radical is a perfect cube. I remember solving these kind of exercises with perfect squares, but I can't figure this one out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $ \root3\of{\frac{7x+2}{x+5}} = N$

$\frac {7x+2}{x+5} = N^3$

$\frac {7x + 35 - 33}{x + 5} = N^3$

$\frac {7x + 35}{x+5} - \frac {33}{x+5} = N^3$

$7 - \frac {33}{x+5} = N^3 \in \mathbb Z$.

So $x+5$ divides $33$.  So $x+5 =\pm 1, \pm 3, \pm 11$ or $\pm 33$.

That means $N^3 = 7-\frac {33}{x+5} = 8,10,18,40,6,4, -4, -26$.

The only one of those that is a perfect cube is $N^2 = 7-\frac {33}{x+5} = 8$ and $\frac {33}{x+5} = -1$.

So $x + 5 = -33$ and $x = -38$.

And check: $\root3\of{\frac{-7*38+2}{-38+5}}= \sqrt[3]{\frac {264}{-33}}=\sqrt[3] 8 = 2$.

Comment: Thank you so much! I really didn't think of this.

Comment: Also, you have a small typo: x = -38 in the end, right?

Comment: Oh, probably and .... Oh yeah.  $x + 5 = -33$ can't get $x = -8$.  *oops*.  Typos.... meh....

Comment: @StefanOctavian It wasn't me first thought either. My first thought was to say on the fourth line $7x + 2 = N^3(x + 5)$ and conclude $(7-N^3)x = 5N^3 - 2$ which is $N$ were restricted to positive would have had finite options but ... well some number theory can tell us $N$ must be even and... maybe other stuff... we can to limits that if $|N|$ is significantly large then $x\approx 5$ and find a lower limit for $N$ (or likewise for $|x|$ significantly large than $N^3 \approx 7$.  It probably would have worked but once we get the idea or ratio limits we might as well do the *exact* ratios.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: for "large" $x$, the radical is between $6$ and $8$

Answer (score 2):

The key point is that if $\sqrt[3]{a}$ is an integer, then $a$ is an integer, because $a$ is the cube of some integer, and the cube of an integer is always an integer.

Therefore, we conclude that $\frac{7x+2}{x+5}$ is an integer. Write this as $\frac{(7x+35) - 33}{x+5} = 7 - \frac{33}{x+5}$.

Now, if $b$ is an integer, so is $7-b$. From this, we see that $\frac{33}{x+5}$ is an integer.

Consequently, $x+5$ is a (not necessarily positive) divisor of $33$. And how many such divisors of $33$ are there? You get the corresponding values of $x$ and test if $7-\frac{33}{x+5}$ is a perfect cube or not.